# How can I import local(my system) png file into React app?

Tags: reactjs, import, png, jsx

first I was trying to get my .png icons from the api which I did it but my browser renders it as image since I used the tag , or even if I want to import from my local system, it still is rendered as image file using  tag...

Comment: did you created your app using create-react-app ?

Comment: you can use like let profileImage = require('../../assets/images/profile_pic.jpg');

Comment: Yes I have used create-react-app

Comment: sir, Im trying to import a PNG file which I can use as an icon

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pbojinov/3ea91a03c7a824abeadc92fda2b27105

Comment: it gave an error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'string' of undefined

Comment: it worked, installed prop-types seperately

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below-mentioned solution. As its created a separate component for Icon like

```
import React, { PropTypes } from "react";

const Icon = props => {
    const styles = {
        img: {
            width: `${props.size}`,
            height: `${props.size}`
        }
    };
    return <img style={styles.img} src={props.icon} />;
};

Icon.propTypes = {
    size: PropTypes.string,
    icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

Icon.defaultProps = {
    size: 32
};

export default Icon;
```

More details [Here](https://gist.github.com/pbojinov/3ea91a03c7a824abeadc92fda2b27105)